# issue in ui-router how to show template without click?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

HI i have found the one template of `UI Router`

Now this is the best `ui-router.`

if you see than if i click to `Route 2` than **open the new page**  and i click to **show List** link than **show to  a listing** but i my question is how to **show listing without clicking** `show list` **show list of Route 2 Thinks**

**[Plunkr Link is](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview)**

Comment: You want to click on "Route2" and show the list automatically without clicking "Show List" link?

Comment: @NewDev Yes i want to click on "Route2" and show the list automatically without clicking "Show List" link with template

Comment: Why can't you just modify your link to be `<a ui-sref="route2.list">Route 2</a>`

Answer (score 0):

To show the list content on page load you can use

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1/list")
```

instead of

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")
```

Similarly, the links can point to the child states:

```
<li><a ui-sref="route1.list">Route 1</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="route2.list">Route 2</a></li>
```